# JQuery: Check whether an Element is Hidden from the user

Tags: jquery

How to check whether a particular element is hidden from the user? In my code, under certain conditions, this code will be called:

```
$("#VersionSelectField").hide('fast');
```

So I have to make sure that if `$("#VersionSelectField")` is hidden, then I would not have to validate the value inside it when I submit the form ( I use [JQuery Validate library](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate) for this purpose).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
$("#VersionSelectField").is(':hidden');
```

Comment: That will just check if it's a hidden input.

Comment: @Rob - This will actually check if it's not visible to the user.  http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/hidden

Comment: i wasn't aware of that selector.  Thanks for bringing it to light for me.

Comment: @Jeff Meatball Yang No, it wont check if the element is 'actually visible to the user'. Eg: The element will not be actually visible if its parent has 'overflow:hidden' and the element is not directly positioned inside the parent.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me:

```
$("#VersionSelectField").css("display") == "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$("#versionselectfield[display='none']").length > 0`.

Comment: Not sure why this was voted down.  Anyone care to explain why checking the display attribute is the wrong answer here?

Comment: I didnt vote you down but the tag would be style="display:none" therefore you selector does not work

Comment: Rob - you can always flag things up to a mod if they suspect to you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, i updated my answer w/ the display attribute.  Nah, don't think its a TOS violation or anything - just rude!

Comment: rob - still wouldnt work as the attribute in this case is style not display. .is(':visible') is the right way.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.  I don't think my answer works when it's an inline style.  The correct answer is :hidden as prev. suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the callback of the hide() method.
For example:

```
$("#VersionSelectField").hide('fast', function() {
    GlobalVersionSelectFieldHidden = true;
});
```

Above is only one method to make use of that, basically the callback will only fires when the animation finished (ie, totally hidden). Of course polluting the global variable scope is very naughty but just a quick example.

Alternatively, checking whether display is "none" like Mark suggest also works, since the JQ effect will totally hide things using that particular css property.